# Customizing/overriding symbol names at compile time

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'm interested in overriding compiler symbol names, generally automatically generated using mangled strings like this:

`modules::ModuleAPI::ModuleAPI()` becomes `_ZN7modules9ModuleAPIC2Ev`

I know there's an alias attribute:

`void name1() __attribute__((alias ("name2")));`

I'd prefer to do the same, except instead of aliasing, overriding it altogether.

Is this possible?

Comment: Might want to clarify the reason for 'overriding' rather than having an alias... for context that might aid answering the question.

Comment: @ChristianStewart: Only as far as it meets the requirement of being a "a **practical**, answerable problem that is unique to software development"  Purely hypothetical questions can be closed.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, this is practical... What you're saying is targeted at questions that are saying things like "how would I make a simple function compile to as large as possible of a binary" or "what would be the best way to build this app"... At least as I interpret it.

Comment: Well, this is more practical than some questions, but less than "I want to customize the symbol name because I'm linking with a module that expects a particular name that isn't a valid C++ identifier" or "I want to customize the symbol name so that my actual function and class names aren't visible to `strings` or `dumpbin` or `nm`"  In the latter case, removing the name altogether using `strip` might be a useful additional suggestion.

Comment: @BenVoigt In this case I'm building a shared library and can't eliminate the symbol altogether. But I'd like to change the names a bit so that it's not quite so obvious what they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, gcc supports this with the [`__asm__` keyword](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html):

```
void name1() __asm__("name2");
```

Comment: What about for classes?

Comment: Classes don't exist at link time.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. So you would change the constructor asm then.

Comment: @ChristianStewart: Class names appear in linker-visible symbol names via name-mangling for functions like `void foo(MyClass &mc)`.  If you wanted to avoid that, you might have to override the asm symbol name for every function that takes an arg (or template parameter) of this class type, as well as the member functions (including constructor) of the class whose name you want to hide.  (The names don't have to use a mangling scheme, they just have to be unique in the linked object.  And globally if they're exported from a shared lib.) IDK if there's a way to just annotate the class declaration.